# ssh-add command does not add my identity to ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I just installed ubuntu 13.10 and I was about to add my identity to my ssh-agent so I open up a Terminal and did this

```
bjorgvin@buntu:~$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
bjorgvin@buntu:~$ ssh-add
bjorgvin@buntu:~$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
bjorgvin@buntu:~$
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From `man ssh-add`:

> ssh-add adds private key identities to the authentication agent,
>        ssh-agent(1).  When run without arguments, it adds the files
>        ~/.ssh/id_rsa, ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa and ~/.ssh/identity.[...]
>
> Identity files should not be readable by anyone but the user.  Note that
>        ssh-add ignores identity files if they are accessible by others.

So, because of `The agent has no identities.` error, you probably don't have those files or maybe those files are accessible by others. You can check these using the following command:

```
ls -l ~/.ssh
```

Also, after you run `ssh-add` command, run `echo $?` to see the error status of the previous command. If exit status returned 0, the command was executed successfully. If exit status returned a non-zero value, the command failed to execute.

See [`man ssh-add`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) for more info.

Comment: true, I don't have those files and the exit value of `ssh-add` was 1 but not 0. there is obviously some problem with my permissions since the files are not created. Any idea how I could fix this?

the directory `~/.ssh` exists (is empty) but it does not show up when I do `ls -l`

Comment: I ran this command `ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N 'password' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` so [man ssh-keygen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) helped, thanks.

Comment: That gave the import hint into the right direction for me. I had multiple ssh keys and first had to add the proper key using ssh-add <keyname>. Then it worked like a charme. thx

Comment: For some reason, I did not have any output when running `ssh-add` after entering passphrase, (it was failing according to `$?` returing 1. I tried to `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa*`  with no luck. I generated a new key from scratch with `ssh-keygen` and then it worked. Sad but at least it's ok now (The failing key was generated using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`, I only ran `ssh-keygen` instead this time).

Comment: I had to do the following in this order:
(if necessary, generate new ssh key, and make sure to add the .pub key to github), then  `cd ~/.ssh && ls -lah` to see read/write permissions in the .ssh folder, change all key(s) with `chmod 400 myKey` then `ssh-add **ABSOLUTE**pathToKey`  if you don't add the **ABSOLUTE** path, it won't work.  Then, test it with `ssh -vT git@github.com`

Answer (score 5):

Additional to the above considerations, I found that if you're using an alternate shell, you may need to configure it to load ssh-agent. For example, in Zsh, one must add `ssh-agent` to `plugins` in `.zshrc`.

This method works great on Ubuntu 17.10 with the latest Zsh

Others found that with `id_ed25519` keys, `rsa` was working without a plugin. After adding `ssh-agent` to `~/.zshrc`, restart the shell with `exec "$SHELL"` and execute: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`

```
Enter passphrase for ~/.ssh/id_ed25519: 
Identity added: ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 (user@host)
```

Comment: Add the ssh-agent plugin to .zshrc via the instructions here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/ssh-agent

Answer (score 2):

As the OP states in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363404/ssh-add-command-does-not-add-my-identity-to-ssh-agent#comment466957_363550):

> I ran this command `ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N 'password' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` so [`man ssh-keygen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to create `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/config` file with `600` permission and

```
Host * 
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile /home/ec2-user/.ssh/[my_private_key]
```

content to make ssh work.